# Typo3 - fluid - for each newsItem.uid

Tags: loops, for-loop, typo3, fluid, tx-news

I'm using Typo3 6.0 and News System 2.0.
I have a custom template using fluid viewhelpers, and I'm displaying news from my database depending on their categories.
So far so good, no problem.

My problem is that I want to loop through all the news records (which are in the table tx_news_domain_model_news) so I can use conditions to filter which ones are displayed, but so far it seems my attempts were in vain.

Why is it possible to loop through news categories like this :

```
<f:for each="{newsItem.categories}" as="category">
     <f:if condition="{category.uid} == 9">
           {category.title} #this is displayed correctly.
     </f:if>
</f:for>
```

but when I try to loop through newsItem.uid, it's not working?

```
<f:for each="{newsItem.uid}" as="pub">
        <f:if condition="{pub} == 5">
             {pub.title}
        </f:if>
</f:for>
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: A news item only has one uid, so why are you looping through it? And also, what are you trying to achieve with all this?

Comment: @Shufla Well I'm trying to loop with a custom field, which is a number, so I can compare it with another. It seems I wasn't able to loop with my custom field, it just didn't work, so I was trying another way using the uid thinking I could use that to access my custom field, but I guess I don't fully understand the ForViewHelper with News... What can I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You messed things a little (actually @Shufla told that yet).

`for each` statement in all languages allows you to iterate *through* some kind of collection. In this case every `newsItem` can have some `categories` connected, so you can for each item iterate through its categories (which are objects). In pseudo code it something like:

```
<f:for each="[cat1,cat2,cat3]" as="currentObject">
    {currentObject.property}
</f:for>
```

UID in TYPO3 is always an integer and is unique so there is not possible to iterate through it, cause pseudo code looks like that (must fail):

```
<f:for each="1" as="currentObject">
    {currentObject.property}
</f:for>
```

I don't know news' view however i just assume that this will work:

```
<f:for each="{news}" as="pub">
        <f:if condition="{pub.uid} == 5">
             {pub.title}
        </f:if>
</f:for>
```

However make sure that you don't perform - nested iteration again, maybe you have all you need in default view's iteration yet?

**Edit**

as you can see `newsItem` is passed to List/Item partial from iteration in News/List.html view (in folder Templates) so you are not able to repeat this iteration in the partial as you have there only ONE news obj available.

If you want/need to make some conditional iteration do it in view: `/typo3conf/ext/news/Resources/Private/Templates/News/List.html`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Apparently I was a bit messed up. Anyways, what I don't understand is that what you justed posted : <f:for each="{news}" as="pub">
        <f:if condition="{pub.uid} == 5">
             {pub.title}
        </f:if>
</f:for> should be working right ? But in my case it's not working, and I do have a news in my tx_news_domain_model_news table with uid 5. So far, it only worked when I tried to loop over categories. Do you know why ? and what else can I do if I want to loop over my news records ?

Comment: I have already filtered the news I want to display the reason why I'm trying to loop over news in the template like this : settings < plugin.tx_news.settings
  settings {
       limit = 4
       startingpoint = 30
       categories = 8 }, but I need to put a special condition, so I thought I could loop over them in the template to do that, is it possible ?